# How to open Browse tab in Apple Music app from our app?

Tags: swift, apple-music, apple-musickit

I am able to open Apple's default Music app using following code:

```
if let appleMusicUrl = URL(string:"music://") {
    UIApplication.shared.open(appleMusicUrl, options: [:]) { done in }
}
```

What I want is that whenever I switch to Music app it opens 'Browse' tab like it does in the following app: https://apps.apple.com/us/app/thinkup-daily-affirmations/id906660772

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution! We can do this by using the URL: "music://music.apple.com/browse"